# How can I modify the mean absolute percentage error to account for the curve direction?

Tags: regression, python, model-evaluation, trend, mape

I am trying to predict the trend of a certain curve in the future (whether it will be increasing, decreasing, or remain constant). For evaluating my prediction, I am using the mean absolute percentage error (MAPE). However, I noticed that the direction really matters in this case, not only the value. For instance, when the actual curve is fluctuating over time, and my prediction is a straight line being the average of that fluctuation, I am getting a small MAPE, which is not fair (or that is what I assume). So I tried to modify the MAPE by including a penalization term that accounts for the difference between subsequent values, which I show below in a piece of python code:

```
def trendLoss(yTrue,yPred):
  loss=0
  mape=0
  alpha=0.5
  beta=0.5

  
  for i in range(len(yTrue)):
    mape+= abs((yTrue[i]-yPred[i])/statistics.mean(yTrue))
  mape/=len(yTrue)

  mean_diff=0
  for i in range(len(yTrue)-1):
    mean_diff+=abs(yTrue[i+1]-yTrue[i])
  mean_diff/=len(yTrue)-1


  made=0
  for i in range(len(yTrue)-1):
    made+= abs(((yTrue[i+1]-yTrue[i])- (yPred[i+1]-yPred[i]))/(mean_diff))
  made/=len(yTrue)-1

  return alpha*mape+beta*made
```

I would like to verify if the above code will give me what I need. I have run it but I saw unexpected results sometimes.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "mathematically sound"?  How exactly does direction matter?  What is it that's "not fair"??

Comment: I mean is my formula going to correctly evaluate the predicted trend direction the way I described? I explained how it matters because I don't care about the value as much as I care about the trend direction. Look, I could be completely wrong in my assumption that MAPE is not enough, but I am seeking an alternative here if my idea has been already studied before.